# Flash Player 11.8 install fails with error code 30 listed in console

Tags: adobe-flash

I am installing the most recent Flash Player 11 for Firefox/Safari, and after running the .pkg from Finder the installation always fails at 50%. I find this error in the console at the end of installation:

```
8/11/13 12:46:07.911 PM [0x0-0xf30f3].com.solidstatenetworks.awkhost: 2013-08-11
12:46:07.910 Adobe Flash Player Install Manager[1628:707] 
Install failed with error code: 30.
```

This has happened for the past few minor releases, not just current (11.8.800.94). How can I complete the installation? I am running Mac OS X 10.7 Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed the installation by running the installer as root from the shell, under its mountpoint at `/Volumes`. The full path to the installer executable's directory is `/Volumes/Adobe Flash Player Installer/Install Adobe Flash Player.app/Contents/MacOS`

[This thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1198672) in Adobe forums describes the underlying problem - the current user can't write to a directory the installer needs. <del>Instead of chmod'ing the folder, I already had [root enabled](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1528?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), and went from there successfully.</del>

**Update:** Commentor is right, root is too risky. Follow the chmod route.

Comment: Due to the poor security of Adobe software, I would advise no one to run them as `root`. Changing the access modes of the necessary directory is an acceptable work around to help an ill conceived installer.
Most notably this software installer hadn't been tested with a real user account ☹.

Answer (score 0):

The thread in the Adobe forums didn't help me. For me Console made no mention of a permissions problem in /var/folders like that thread says. I had to use sudo on the command line to get it installed. Pity but what else can one do.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to running the installation program from the Terminal command line as 'root', I also had to go into Safari Preferences / Security / Plug-In Settings and change the Adobe Flash Player's "When visiting other web sites" from "No" to "Ask".

Answer (score -1):

Use the sudo command then copy and paste where the executable file is at. It worked for me with the latest version. I think the problem is caused by rootless.